# gets() takes arguments in C language

Tags: c, gets

I have used the `gets()` function in my program for getting string from user.
When I check `gets()` with multiple arguments I was shocked.
The `gets()` takes many number of arguments, but I don't know then number of arguments taken by `gets()`, and what is the actual use of these all arguments.

```
void main()
{
    char str[10];
    printf("Enter the String...:");
    gets(str,5,5,5,5,5);
    puts(str);
}
```

The code has no error but it will display the same argument which it is given as input.

```
input String : This is a Tesing.
output String : This is a Tesing.
```

Comment: I'd suggest turning on warnings in your compiler and fixing them before running the code. If you get no warnings or errors, throw your compiler away.

Comment: ***`int`*** `main()`...

Comment: I'm not sure [why it does](http://ideone.com/CvdFYk), (atleast how it links) but always include the [standard header](http://ideone.com/C8PFts)

Comment: Read the function's documantation and you get enlightend about the number of arguments the function ought to take.

Comment: @alk I have read this function documentation in help. but there is no specification for more than one arguments.

Comment: The simple rule with respect to `gets()` is to for-`gets()` that it exists.  It is a lethal function; it is trivial to create buffer (stack) overflows with it.  The first internet worm, the Morris Worm of 1988, exploited a program that used `gets()`.  You should use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` instead — not that TCC 3.0 is likely to have POSIX `getline()` — but be aware of the newlines from these.  Pretend that using `gets()` will cause a core dump.  In general, make sure that functions are declared before they are used.  And always include standard headers for standard functions.

Comment: Don't use gets().  Ever.  It's been the achilles heel of C for decades.

Answer (score 3):

`gets()` takes only one argument.

Probably what happens is that because you **didn't include `<stdio.h>`**, the compiler has no idea what the prototype of it, didn't find the compilation error, it happened to work.

The correct form of the whole program should be (even though I'm still using `gets()`):

```
#include <stdio.h>     
int  main() { 
    char str[10];
    printf("Enter the String...:");
    gets(str,5,5,5,5,5);
    puts(str);
}
```

When I tested under GCC, it pops an error:

```
error: too many arguments to function 'gets'
```

And don't use `gets()`, it's dangerous and has been removed in C11. Use `fgets()` instead:

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

---

**EDIT**: thanks for @abelenky's answer and @chux's comment, I confirmed my guess.

In C11 6.5.2.2 *Function calls* subsection 2 (in *Constraints*):

> **If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that includes a prototype, the number of arguments shall agree with the number of parameters. **Each argument shall
>   have a type such that its value may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version
>   of the type of its corresponding parameter.

In subsection 6 (in *Semantics*):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>   have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the default argument promotions. **If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>   behavior is undefined.** ...

So what happened is, without the header `stdio.h`, the compiler doesn't know the prototype of `gets()`, the behavior is undefined, following subsection 6 above.

With the header, the compiler knows the prototype, according to subsection 2 above, it's required to generate diagnostic message as it's a constraint.

Comment: I am using Turbo C++, version 3.0. And it will not generate the error.

Comment: @BharatMevada Ah, I see. My advice: throw it away, it's very old and known to be full of bugs.

Comment: @YuHao Any explanation for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619661/gets-takes-arguments-in-c-language#comment29125490_19619661) ?

Comment: @YuHao : This is enough for me. thanks. Now i will use the latest version.

Comment: @P0W I haven't looked it up, but I guess passing wrong number of arguments is undefined behavior, one compiler supporting it isn't enough.

Comment: @YuHao Yeah, I think some thing _goofy_ with online compilers

Comment: @YuHao Which compiler is suitable for C programming. I am new learner.

Comment: @P0W I tested again, try with the correct header, and it will generates the error.

Comment: Use GCC or clang.  At a pinch, if you work on Windows, use MSVC.  You need a compiler that's conformant to modern standards (which should rule out MSVC; it conforms to C89 and not to the old C99 or new C11 standards — however, there are other reasons for using it in its niche) and that generates good diagnostics.

Comment: @YuHao I tested this with including the proper header file stdio.h Thanks

Comment: Recommend instead `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);`

Answer (score 1):

In the C language, you are allowed to pass as many arguments to a function as you want.

(as an example, see `printf`, which can take an arbitrary number of arguments)

That does ***not*** mean that the function you call will use those arguments at all.
Each function will only process the arguments *it is documented to process*.

Extra arguments are ***ignored***.

So, go ahead, and pass even more arguments to `gets`.  It won't change anything.
`gets` will still only use the first argument, as it is [documented to](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/).

Comment: That's incorrect. `printf` can take multiple arguments because it's a variable arguments function (the prototype is `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);` , but `gets` is not.

Comment: @YuHao: In C, the *CALLER* both pushes arguments on the stack, and cleans up the arguments after the function returns..  If there are extra arguments on the stack, the *CALLEE* does not care, and is not aware of extra arguments.  As a result, you can call with extra arguments.  (The compiler may generate warnings, but the code will function properly)

Comment: Maybe some compiler implements function calling in that way, but I'm pretty sure that's not what the C standard says. A good compiler should generate errors on functions called with incorrect number of parameters. Like I said, functions like `printf` and `scanf` are variable arguments function, that's not an evidence to support other functions can take variable arguments.

Comment: @Yu Hao C11dr 6.5.2.2 6 says "… If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined. …".  So it does not have to be an error and may operate as abelenky suggests. Your point focuses on errors at compile time.  abelenky focuses on behavior at run time.

Comment: @chux That makes sense, but with some limitations. Actually that explains my guess, the problem is because of lack of prototype. I'll modify my answer. Again, `printf` isn't an example to demonstrate this point.